# Two fixed position elements spark some problems

Tags: html, css, hover, css-position

When I try to add `position: fixed;` rules for two elements in CSS, `:hover` doesn't properly work on the children of the first element. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

I know the problem is with the fixed rule because when I remove it from the second element, the code works as intended.

```css
nav {
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  width: 96.5vw;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: rgb(255, 216, 143);
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

nav div {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1vh;
  flex-grow: 0.1;
}

nav div:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

#boxar {
  border: 10px solid rgb(156, 125, 0);
  position: fixed;
  /*comment this line out*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 95vw;
  height: 97vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="homeb">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="teamb">
    <h1>Team</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="standb">
    <h1>Standings</h1>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="boxar"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you afixing two elements? Or, why isn't `#boxar` inside the navbar? The easy solution is probably to put both in a fixed container.

Comment: If that's the case this is the wrong strategy. Let's hear from them, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because boxer div is covering the div you are trying to hover on.
so I put negative z-index on boxar to be behind hover div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>


<style>
  nav {
    border: 5px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
    width: 99.3%;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 216, 143);
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  
  nav div {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: gold;
    position: relative;
    
    flex-grow: 0.1;
  }
  
  nav div:hover {
    background-color: red;
  
  }
  
  #boxar {
    border: 10px solid rgb(156, 125, 0);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 98.6%;
    height: 97vh;
    z-index: -1;
  }
</style>

<body>


  <nav>
    <div id="homeb">
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="teamb">
      <h1>Team</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="standb">
      <h1>Standings</h1>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="boxar"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I like your code but it's not very standard to put every single position by yourself.
I recommend the code in the link below:

[Flex navbar at codepen](https://codepen.io/Avi-Qiyan/pen/bGmGxGq)